# executemany(sql,value) wont execute. python pyodbc

Tags: python, pyodbc

```
def fast_execute():
    mydb = pyodbc.connect(connection_string,autocommit=True)
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("use care_new")
    mycursor.execute("truncate dummytable")
    print('executed 1')
    mycursor.fast_executemany = True
    print('executed 2')
    query = "insert into dummytable(ID, Name) values(?,?)"
    value =  [((f'{i}'),(f'Names{str(i)}'),) for i in range(10000)]
    t0 = time.time()
    print('executed 3')
    mycursor.executemany(query, value)
    print('executed 4')
    print(f'{time.time() - t0:.1f} seconds for fast execute many')
    mydb.close()
```

> **Output**

```
executed 1
executed 2
executed 3
```

I cant figure out why program wont execute `mycursor.executemany(query,value)` and post steps.

If i comment out `mycursor.fast_executemany = True` line, it works fine. But that takes around 45 secs since Im dealing with 10000 records.

Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You have too many levels of nesting in your list of tuples. Each row being inserted is just a normal tuple of 2 elements.

There's also no need to format the ID as a string.

```
value =  [(i, f'Names{str(i)}') for i in range(10000)]
```

Comment: Okay, that was definitely useful. But it doesn't solve the original problem. Why isn't it executing the `mycursor.executemany(query,value)` step and the steps after it.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-i-made-inserts-into-sql-server-100x-faster-with-pyodbc-5a0b5afdba5) is related. But it says they were getting an exception when they tried to use it. If you're not getting an exception I don't know why it wouldn't run.